# List of image data without over exposed pixels

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, image-processing

I have a greyscale png `image` and want to produce a list of all pixel values which are not 1 for analyzing them further.

`image`:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com//SC0F3.png"];

RepeatedTiming[
 imageData = ImageData[image]; 
 imageDataWithout1 = DeleteCases[Flatten@imageData, value_ /; value == 1];
 ]
 {0.13, Null}

(*imageDataWithout1 is the resulting list *)
```

Check:

```
Dimensions[Flatten@imageData] - Dimensions[imageDataWithout1]

{34323}

Count[Flatten@imageData, value_ /; value == 1]

34323
```

Can this also be done different, since the **code is relatively slow**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my machine `Pick` seems to be way faster:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com//SC0F3.png"];
RepeatedTiming[imageData = ImageData[image];
 imageDataWithout1 = 
  DeleteCases[Flatten@imageData, value_ /; value == 1];]
imageDataWithout1 // Dimensions
(* {0.132, Null}
{253007} *)

RepeatedTiming[imageData = ImageData[image];
 imageDataWithout1 = 
  Pick[#, UnitStep[# - 1.0], 0] &@Flatten@imageData;]
imageDataWithout1 // Dimensions
(* {0.0058, Null}
{253007} *)
```

Comment: Why is this so fast? ... incredible ... thanks

Comment: @mrz I think `DeleteCases` and `Select` apply your test function sequentially. `UnitStep` is `Listable` so it applies `UnitStep[# - 1.0]` to a list more effectively.